# How to test the difference between fastjson and gson in serialization and deserialization

Tags: automated-testing

The project uses Gson to replace Fastjson. These two packages have some differences in serialization and deserialization. As a software test engineer, how do I perform regression testing?

Comment: Any problems in running the unit tests for the wrapper class that interacts with Gson and Fastjson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would:

- run existing regression tests for serialization and deserialization to see if the system still performs the same way. These can be unit tests or integration tests. You may also consider running existing performance regression tests if that's of concern for your specific system.
- add more tests that stress differences between Gson and Fastjson, if these areas are not covered yet.